# Fast way to send current line to the shell in Vim

Tags: vim, shell

Say that the current line in Vim contains:

```
ls /home
```

(or whatever shell command). Thus, what is a fast way to send this line to the (bash) shell and read the results in Vim? And without using plug-ins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to put `:!` at the front of the line (with `I:!`), then `yy` to yank the line into the unnamed register, and finally use `@"` to call the unnamed (`"`) register as a macro. To vim, this is exactly equivalent to typing

```
:!ls /home
```

in normal mode. If, like me, you have `;` and `:` switched around in your .vimrc for normal mode, you'll have to insert a semicolon instead.

It's probably possible to alter the register in-place, rather than prepending to an actual line.

---

It's also possible to do it by `y$` yanking to the end of the line (without the above editing), then typing

```
:!<c-r>"
```

...(`<c-r>` meaning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) which will expand to

```
:!ls /home
```

(or whatever the command you yanked was). You need to use `y$` rather than `yy` because otherwise it will expand to

```
:ls /home^M
```

`^M` there representing the newline; this is easy enough to delete with a single backspace, though.

This second method might be slightly faster, but anything that involves the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key seems faintly un-vim-like to me.

Comment: `yy` plus `:!c-r"Backspace` is 6 keystrokes, but probably the faster way. Btw what's the problem with `^M`?

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly, but leaving it there prevents the command from working...

Answer (score 2):

You can send the current line as a command by simply invoking:

```
:.!bash -e
```

The line in the opened buffered will be replaced by the output of that command.

If you'd rather preserve the original line, you can send the output to another buffer with:

```
:.w !bash -e
```

Answer (score 0):

## append the result below the line

You can do it in six key strokes: `:r!<C-R><C-L><CR>`

## replace the line by the result:

You can do it in five key strokes: `!!<C-R><C-L><CR>`

But this will also feed the line itself as standard input to the command so it might cause side effects.
To prevent that from happening, you can do `0D!!<C-R>"<CR>`